# Checkbook-like register for credit card purchases?

Tags: android, finance

I would like to record my credit card purchases as I make them on my android phone, and then have those purchases automatically reconciled against my monthly statement. I would like them to be automatically reconciled the way mint does, where I give it my bank's login information. Or, any other way that this could be done automatically is fine by me. That way unknown charges, or charges of the wrong amount, will be automatically shown to me.

I have mint, which connects to my bank accounts and aggregates this functionality automatically, but their app doesn't have this capability. Is there any app out there for Android like this?

Comment: Thanks for update! Time for comment-cleanup. Let's remove the (now obsolete) first three :)

Comment: And while I have no direct recommendation for you (I don't do finances on my mobiles), until an answer pops up (hopefully soon) you might wish to peek into my section of [finance apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/catmin/applists/category/named/finance). Good luck!

Comment: I'm confused as to what mint doesn't do that you're requiring. You've specifically stated mint can't, so I'm just trying to figure out what you're looking for.

Comment: @Raystafarian I'm look to have an app on my android smartphone where I enter credit card purchases as I make them. Then, when my bank issues my monthly statement, this app would show me if there are any differences between what my bank said my credit card purchases are, versus what I've recorded. That way, if someone has made a fraudulent charge, or a vendor charge the wrong amount, the app can automatically show that to me. This saves me going over my statement at the end of the month, trying to remember all the charge I made, and perhaps making a mistake.

Comment: When you reconcile at month end, do you reconcile to receipts?

Comment: Sometimes I do, but it's a pain to sort through some 30+ receipts. Also, there are instance where I didn't get the receipt, such as when the gas station pump didn't print it out, and I didn't feel like going inside.

What I am really looking for is convenience and automation. When I reconcile by memory or by receipt, I am human and can make mistakes. If I had an app, it presumably would make less mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Bill Guard app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.billguard.android) does what I want, but from the other way around. It notifies me when there are new charges to my cards, instead of reconciling the statement.

Answer (score 0):

[Clarity Money](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.claritymoney.android.prod&hl=en_US) shows new/recent credit card charges.